# can I dynamically reduce the page size by compressing / decompressing its HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gzip, http-compression

I want to know if I can apply compression/decompression to my existing aspx page. What I want to say is that,

1. I must be able to compress the response send by the server in some compressed format . **Please note, only the HTML Source to be compressed not entire aspx page to some .zip file format.** I am saying so, as If copy the rendered HTML of my page in notepad and check its sizes, it varies in between 134kB-200kB (with Viewstates. And I can't disable that). I dont want to process my network that much load. I want it minmal, say 40-50kB is enough.
2. At client machine that compressed HTML source will get decompressed and rendered as normal aspx page.
3. **Most Imp, my page are up and running**. I need some HTTPHandler or Module or some sort of addin that will not require a lot of changes in my existing code. Can be used by making change in web.config . Minimal changes in aspx or master pages are welcome. In short , some global way of doing this.

Comment: Have you googled `web.config compression`?

Comment: @I4V .. no actually I dont have any idea about compression. I searched but I hav'nt got any thing satisfactory

Comment: Strange, because I found many useful docs in the first result page.

Comment: Thanks @I4V .. I got one .. actually whatever I got was for IIS level and since I am on shared hosting that does not allow me change the underlying settings and also they has put various limitations on their IIS.

Comment: ayways i got this one on your suggestion and I put it in my config. See the url  http://am-blog.no-ip.org/BlogEngine/post/2010/11/23/Enable-Gzip-compression-in-ASPNET-using-webconfig-configuration.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that is done by IIS and the browser. Just set static and dinamyc compression on IIS and you're done.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753681.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754668.aspx

Comment: I am on shared hosting and my host do not allow  me to change  IIS settings. I need code level solution

Comment: Then see this other article.
http://labs.kaliko.com/2010/09/turn-off-http-compression-from.html